# Using manage.py commands on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have deployed my first web application to google cloud and I have been having a lot of difficulties on my first trip.

My main question (and reason for creating this post) is how to execute commands with manage.py like migrations? If that is not possible, how to handle migrations in the database?

I'm having trouble working in the cloud, I'm using the Cloud SQL for Postgresql and App Engine Flexible environment, I would appreciate if the more experienced ones could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer the question `how` we should know what did you already try

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Augusto, can you share what you have already tried so we can point you in the right direction?

Comment: The problem is that I haven't been able to do anything yet, normally I look for an answer on SO or reddit for a day or two and find the answer. This time I crashed completely, because I can't find anything about it anywhere.

I can't even access django admin page, because i don't know how to execute the first migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I solved it by using a local copy of Cloud SQL Proxy and actually it was pretty easy.

Found the answer here https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#deploying_the_app_to_the_standard_environment_

I highlighted the most important part of this article in my TIL repository, if you are looking to a quicker answer.
https://github.com/jaocfilho/til/blob/master/google-cloud-platform/proxy-with-sql-instance.md

Thanks everyone.

Comment: migrating database from localhost is easy, but how to do it from CI job. It is not very smart to keep database migrations out of the flow of continuous integration.... There is many pits you can step into :-(